# Who owns the Star Wars Legends books?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, copyright

Hypothetically, say I wanted to make a movie version of the Heir to the Empire series, would Disney be the one who owns the material and I would need to get permission from them or would I go to Timothy Zahns for permission to make the movie?

Comment: Disney definitely owns the trademarked Star Wars material at this time. As for the copyright itself, I suspect that he did it as work for hire, which means Lucas's company gained the rights upon writing, which probably transferred to Disney.

Comment: For any given book, odds are Valorum owns it.

Comment: @MiloP - I'm pretty sure I don't own every Legends book. There's a bunch of Young Reader books that are quite rare

Comment: Yup, I'm still praying that Disney will one day consider opening up Legends to movies or TV and they can even do that multi-verse crap they've done to Marvel.  In the end, all I want is movie of Shadows of the Empire.  A guy can dream!

Comment: remove dc superheroes and 80% of your  childhood is now owned by disney

Comment: Make Shatterpoint next. Love me some Mace Windu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disney own the full rights, via their [purchase of Lucasfilm](https://ew.com/article/2012/12/21/walt-disney-completes-lucasfilm-acquisition/)

> Star Wars: Heir to the Empire is a work of fiction. Names, places, and incidents either are products of the author’s imagination or are used fictitiously.
> **Copyright © 2011 by Lucasfilm Ltd. & ® or ™ where indicated.**
>
> **All Rights Reserved. Used Under Authorization.**
>
> <sub><sup>Heir to the Empire - Ballantine Special Edition 2011</sup></sub>

Work that is produced under licence rarely requires *permission* from the author to be adapted into other formats (such as your upcoming film), although their contract may include additional residuals and royalties and the right to be consulted on the use of any characters they have created.

Comment: so does that mean all the Star Wars Legends books are now owned by Disney?

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes - Anything with a LucasArts or Lucasfilm badge on it is now owned by Disney.

Comment: thanks for the information. I guess no more Star Wars legends movie ideas then

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes - Disney have said that they reserve the right to include Legends material in their shows and films.

Comment: (and already have done so; Thrawn shows up in the animated shows, and I suspect is likely to make his way into live-action soon)

Comment: I suppose I could mention here the fact that Disney owns the books, and has been somewhat lax in paying royalties to the authors.  https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/business/business-news/star-wars-author-royalties-disney-1234951422/

Comment: @VBartilucci - That's certainly what the authors allege. Disney have stated that it's the job of the original publishers to keep the authors apprised of their royalties. This is like blaming McDonald's Corporatr HQ for the actions of a franchise owner. It gets big publicity to say "Disney did X", when in reality the book guy at Disney only does business with the publishers